# LG Connect SDK issue with Android 7

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, classloader, live-connect-sdk

I have an app that works fine with Android 6, but freezes on Android 7. All I have is added ConnectSDK by LG (http://www.svlconnectsdk.com/docs/1-6-0/android/). The app freezes as soon as I call start on DiscoveryManager's object. And I get the following stacktrace:

> 10-26 13:32:51.678: W/System(7569): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.testconnectsdk.test-1/lib/arm64
>   10-26 13:32:51.774: W/System.err(7569): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
>   10-26 13:32:51.774: W/System.err(7569):              at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
>   10-26 13:32:51.774: W/System.err(7569):              at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:147)
>   10-26 13:32:51.774: W/System.err(7569):              at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:808)
>   10-26 13:32:51.774: W/System.err(7569):              at com.connectsdk.discovery.provider.ssdp.SSDPClient.multicastReceive(SSDPClient.java:109)
>   10-26 13:32:51.774: W/System.err(7569):              at com.connectsdk.discovery.provider.SSDPDiscoveryProvider$2.run(SSDPDiscoveryProvider.java:271)
>   10-26 13:32:51.774: W/System.err(7569):              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

The code is very simple :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DiscoveryManagerListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DiscoveryManager.init(getApplicationContext(), null);
        final DiscoveryManager dm = DiscoveryManager.getInstance();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                dm.addListener(MainActivity.this);
            }
        }, 2000);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                dm.start();
            }
        }, 4000);



        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 6000);

    }

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onDeviceAdded(DiscoveryManager manager, ConnectableDevice device) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "onDeviceAdded");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceUpdated(DiscoveryManager manager, ConnectableDevice device) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "onDeviceUpdated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceRemoved(DiscoveryManager manager, ConnectableDevice device) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "onDeviceRemoved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDiscoveryFailed(DiscoveryManager manager, ServiceCommandError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "onDiscoveryFailed");
    }
}
```

Any idea why is it crashing? Pasting my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testconnectsdk.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="OtherActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Kindly please help. Badly need it. Thanks

Comment: I did reproduce this, then opened an [issue](https://github.com/ConnectSDK/Connect-SDK-Android/issues/362) on the connect-sdk-android repo. Please subscribe & comment. Also, you don't need postDelayed, call addListener & start instantly.